# pandas: fill nan values based on another column with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby

I have two tables which I am trying to merge, `df_a` and `df_b`, but both are missing some values. The merge happens fine, however I'm trying to speed up the process of filling in the `NaN` values after the merge.

### The data:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 5, 3],
    'name': [np.nan, 'two', 'three', 'one', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'length': ['l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l1', 'l6', np.nan, np.nan],
    'Q1': [11, 22, 33, 11, 66, 55, 33],
    'Q2': [111, 222, 333, 111, 666, 555, 333]})

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 7, 3],
    'name': ['five', 'two', 'four', 'one_extra', 'three', 'one', 'seven', 'three'],
    'length': ['l5', 'l2', 'l4', 'l1', 'l3', 'l1', 'l7', 'l3_extra'],
    'Q1': [2055, 2022, 2044, 2011, 2033, 2011, 2077, 2033],
    'Q2': [2055, 2022, 2044, 2011, 2033, 2011, 2077, 2033]})

df_m = df_a.merge(df_b, on=['id', 'name', 'length'], how='outer',
                  suffixes=['_a', '_b'])
Output:

       id   name length  Q1   Q2
    0   1    NaN     l1  11  111
    1   2    two     l2  22  222
    2   3  three     l3  33  333
    3   1    one     l1  11  111
    4   6    NaN     l6  66  666
    5   5    NaN    NaN  55  555
    6   3    NaN    NaN  33  333

       id       name    length    Q1    Q2
    0   5       five        l5  2055  2055
    1   2        two        l2  2022  2022
    2   4       four        l4  2044  2044
    3   1  one_extra        l1  2011  2011
    4   3      three        l3  2033  2033
    5   1        one        l1  2011  2011
    6   7      seven        l7  2077  2077
    7   3      three  l3_extra  2033  2033

        id       name    length  Q1_a   Q2_a    Q1_b    Q2_b
    0    1        NaN        l1  11.0  111.0     NaN     NaN
    3    1        one        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
    9    1  one_extra        l1   NaN    NaN  2011.0  2011.0
    1    2        two        l2  22.0  222.0  2022.0  2022.0
    2    3      three        l3  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
    6    3        NaN       NaN  33.0  333.0     NaN     NaN
    11   3      three  l3_extra   NaN    NaN  2033.0  2033.0
    8    4       four        l4   NaN    NaN  2044.0  2044.0
    5    5        NaN       NaN  55.0  555.0     NaN     NaN
    7    5       five        l5   NaN    NaN  2055.0  2055.0
    4    6        NaN        l6  66.0  666.0     NaN     NaN
    10   7      seven        l7   NaN    NaN  2077.0  2077.0
```

### The Endpoint

I'm trying to get `df_m` into a state where any `NaN` values are filled in based on their values from a corresponding `id` column. Any time there's a duplicate `id`, I want to keep both values, so that I end up with the following `df`:

```
   id       name    length  Q1_a   Q2_a    Q1_b    Q2_b
0   1        one        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
1   1  one_extra        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
2   2        two        l2  22.0  222.0  2022.0  2022.0
3   3      three        l3  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
4   3      three  l3_extra  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
5   4       four        l4   NaN    NaN  2044.0  2044.0
6   5       five        l5  55.0  555.0  2055.0  2055.0
7   6        NaN        l6  66.0  666.0     NaN     NaN
8   7      seven        l7   NaN    NaN  2077.0  2077.0
```

Note that there are some `NaN` values, where there was an entry in one table, and not in the other, e.g. there's no entry in `df_a` for `id=4`, so there's `NaN`s at `Q1_a` and `Q2_a`.

### My solution so far

The following works, but I'd like to vectorise this code, as it takes more than 4 seconds with only ~200 rows:

```
dupe_ids = pd.value_counts(df_m.id)[
    pd.value_counts(df_m.id) > 1].index.values

for dupe_id in dupe_ids:
    df_m.loc[df_m.id == dupe_id] = df_m.loc[df_m.id == dupe_id].ffill().bfill()

df_m = df_m.drop_duplicates().sort_values(by='id').reset_index(drop=True)
```

I tried vectorising the code, as follows, but the results were strange (see `id=4`).

```
df_m.sort_values(by='id').groupby(
    'id').ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

Output:

       id       name    length  Q1_a   Q2_a    Q1_b    Q2_b
    0   1        one        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
    1   1  one_extra        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
    2   2        two        l2  22.0  222.0  2022.0  2022.0
    3   3      three        l3  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
    4   3      three  l3_extra  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
    5   4       four        l4  55.0  555.0  2044.0  2044.0
    6   5       five        l5  55.0  555.0  2055.0  2055.0
    7   6      seven        l6  66.0  666.0  2077.0  2077.0
    8   7      seven        l7   NaN    NaN  2077.0  2077.0
```

The two tables I'm actually trying to merge are quite a bit more complex, so the example above leads to much more strange behaviour than is seen there. There are over 100 columns, and different columns can have `NaN` values in different places.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you need to perform a `ffill` + `bfill` both groupwise. Your current vectorisation attempt performs the `ffill` groupwise only.

```
res = df_m.sort_values('id')\
          .groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())\
          .drop_duplicates()

print(res)

    id       name    length  Q1_a   Q2_a    Q1_b    Q2_b
0    1        one        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
9    1  one_extra        l1  11.0  111.0  2011.0  2011.0
1    2        two        l2  22.0  222.0  2022.0  2022.0
2    3      three        l3  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
11   3      three  l3_extra  33.0  333.0  2033.0  2033.0
8    4       four        l4   NaN    NaN  2044.0  2044.0
5    5       five        l5  55.0  555.0  2055.0  2055.0
4    6        NaN        l6  66.0  666.0     NaN     NaN
10   7      seven        l7   NaN    NaN  2077.0  2077.0
```

Comment: Ah! Jaysus I can't believe I missed that. Would the following be a small bit faster, to avoid having to sue `.apply()`? `df_m.sort_values(by='id').groupby('id').ffill().groupby('id').bfill()`

Comment: @KevL, I don't *think* it would be faster, since you are repeating the `GroupBy` operation. But I advise you test it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jpp for his answer.

Just to check, I've timed his solution against the one in my reply to his answer.

```
Input:
df_m = df_m.append([df_m] * 10000, ignore_index=True) 

%timeit df_r1 = df_m\
          .groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())\
          .drop_duplicates()

%timeit df_r2 = df_m.groupby('id').ffill().groupby('id').bfill().drop_duplicates()

Output:
114 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
112 ms ± 515 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So, it seems with 100,000 rows it's *very* close.